# Pass a class atrribute to function outside of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a class called "Test" with attributes "hp" and "max_hp". Now I want to pass these attributes as arguments to an outside function (it is outside the class since I want to use it with other instances of other classes), and add 1 to the attribute if it is not equal to the max attribute. My problem is that even though the function is called and test.hp and test.max_hp passed as arguments, they don't change.

Here's the code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 10
        self.max_hp = self.hp

def recovery_action(attribute, max_attribute):
    if attribute == max_attribute:
        pass
    else:
        attribute += 1


test = Test()
test.hp -= 5
print(f'test.hp - {test.hp}')
recovery_action(test.hp, test.max_hp)
print(f'test.hp after recovery - {test.hp}')
```

The problem is that the output looks like this:

```
test.hp -  5
test.hp after recovery - 5
```

I passed the test.hp as an argument and it wasn't equal to test.max_hp, so 1 should have been added to it - but it stayed the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Integers in python are **immutable**, so when you pass them to a function and change them it creates a copy of them instead of changing the original. you should pass the test instance to the function and edit it directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not really changing the attribute in your function.
Basically what you do is call `recovery_action(5,10)`.

If you want to actually change the attribute, you can return the result and assign it, like that:

```py
def recovery_action(attribute, max_attribute):
    if attribute != max_attribute:
        return attribute + 1
    return attribute
```

Then you can run:
`test.hp = recovery_action(test.hp, test.max_hp)`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `attribute` lives in the scope of `recovery_action`. However, what you would want is to actually reference the class, so that changes are saved outside the scope of the function. A solution could be:

```py
def recovery_action(test: Test):
    if test.hp == test.max_hp:
        pass
    else:
        test.hp += 1
```

This function passes an instance of `Test` to the function (hence the `: Test` part). The rest of the function is straightforward. Now, you address the variable in the object you pass to the function and thus remains changed after the function ends.

Answer (score 0):

There is no object representing the attribute itself; `test.max_hp` is just an expression that evaluates to the *value* of the attribute. Since an `int` is immutable, you can't change the value by passing it as an argument. You would need to pass the object and the *name* of the attribute as two separate arguments, and have the function operate on the object directly.

```
def recovery_action(obj, attribute, max_):
    if getattr(obj, attribute) == max_:
        pass
    else:
        setattr(obj, attribute, attribute + 1)


recovery_action(test, 'hp', test.max_hp)
```

Note that your function doesn't care that the maximum value *comes from* an object attribute; it only cares that it is some integer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the argument of a function will not change the variable you have passed in to that function. You can return the changed variable and reassign the class attribute.

Also maybe creating getter and setter of the attributes is a good idea to access and change attributes of a class.